# How to compare the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function for balls and cubes?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, harmonic-analysis

I am currently working through a set of notes I found on the internet at: http://math.msu.edu/~charlesb/Notes/DuoChapter2.pdf

I am up to page 8, and the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function for balls has just been introduced. Then it says that we can also define maximal functions over cubes centred at $x$. Then there is the phrase:
"Furthermore, since the $n$-dimensional volumes of the unit cube and unit ball are equal up to a multiplicative
constant depending only on $n$, it is immediate that $Mf$ and $M'f$ are comparable in the sense that $c_nM'f(x)\leq Mf(x)\leq C_nM'f(x)$
for constants $c_n$ and $C_N$ only depending on $n$."

It may be immediate to the author but it is not at all to me! I cannot understand why this is true. Does anyone have a proof? And is there a formula for $c_n$ and $C_n$?

All I can think of is maybe it's possible to come up with some sort of comparison between the size of a ball and the size of a cube both using the same $r$, but then the integrals may not be equal in order to compare the entire maximal funnction...

Comment: The point is that any ball will both contain a cube *and* itself be contained in a larger cube. For the maximal function you are integrating the norm of the function, so something positive - not much to worry about.

Comment: You can embed a cube in a ball embedded in a cube. Think about squares.

Comment: @TyrCurtis In $R^2$, a circle of radius $r$ can fit inside a square with sides $2r$. Here the size of the ball is $\pi r^2$ and the size of the cube $4r^2$. Then a square of sides $\sqrt{2}r$ can fit inside the same circle. I can see how the size of the ball and cube can be compared. But how does the integral of the function over the ball/cube figure into it? Doesn't the function $f$ determine what the $c_n$ and $C_n$ values would be? How does it only depend on $n$?

Comment: @Arkamis See previous comment.

Comment: @TyrCurtis So for R^2, the ball inside the cube, $|B|=\pi r^2$ and $|Q|=4r^2$ so $|B|\leq \frac{\pi}{4}|Q|$? How does the integral change this?

Comment: You're taking measures over sets. The maximal function is given by $\sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{E_r(x)} \int_{E_r(x)} |f(x)|$. The integral doesn't change the value of the set you're integrating over; rather the set you're integrating over changes the value of the integral. So you could say this:
$$\int_{S_{\sqrt{2}r}(x)} |f| \le \int_{B_r(x)} |f| \le \int_{S_{2r}(x)} |f|$$
where $S$ denotes a cube, and $B$ denotes a ball.

Comment: In any case, since we're taking the $\sup$ over *all* $r>0$, it doesn't matter whether we take balls or cubes. There is some $r$ for which a ball covers a cube of $r'$ and vice versa. This is generalized to the notion of arbitrary sets that "shrink nicely". In this sense, we can develop the fundamental theorem of calculus using centered intervals, for instance: $\int_{x-\frac{\delta}{2}}^{x+\frac{\delta}{2}} f'(x) = f(x+\delta/2)-f(x-\delta/2)$ etc

Comment: @Arkamis So just looking at the inequality on the right, we have $\int_B \leq \int_S$ and we also have $\frac{1}{|B|}\geq \frac{4}{\pi}\frac{1}{|Q|}$. How do we combine these two inequalities in order to resemble the maximal function? One has the ball part being smaller and the other has the cube part being smaller.

Comment: $|B_r(x)| = \frac{4}{\pi}|S_r(x)|$. This is an equality. They are constant multiples of each other. No greater-than/less-than signs. The area of the inscribed circle is always $\pi/4$ of the area of the square it's inside.

Comment: @Arkamis Of course it is - my mistake! So then we can say that $\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{|S_{\sqrt{2}r}|}\int_{S_{\sqrt{2}r}} \leq \frac{1}{|B_r|}\int_{B_r}\leq \frac{4}{\pi}\frac{1}{|S_{2r}|}\int_{S_{2r}}$ for the squares and circle described above? And then finding supremums doesn't affect the inequality, so $c_n=\frac{2}{\pi}$ and $C_n=\frac{4}{\pi}$ for this example? Also, if this is right, is there a formula for the volumes of the balls and cubes for $R^n$? For $R^2$, it's just the area of a square or circle and for $R^3$, it's the volume of a normal cube and sphere. What is it for $R^n$?

Comment: @BenJames Something like $\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n+1)}$ or somesuch. It's easily googleable :)

Comment: @Arkamis I found the formula for the balls and it is $|B_r| = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)}r^n$. I am googling volume of cube and getting a billion results telling me a 3D cube of side length $2r$ has volume $8r^3$ which isn't helpful. I am guessing that higher dimension cubes follow the pattern $|S_r|=r^n$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube#Coordinates

Comment: @Arkamis Thanks! I didn't know the term hypercube, but my guess was right :)

Answer (score 3):

> **Theorem.** Let $\mathcal{M}$ and $M$ denote the uncentered and centered Hardy-Littlewood maximal function using
>   balls, and let $\mathcal{M}_{c}$ and $M_{c}$ denote the uncentered and centered Hardy-Littlewood maximal
>   function using cubes. For $f\in L_{loc}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$,
>
> $$\dfrac{2^{n}}{(v_{n}n^{n/2})}\leq\dfrac{M(f)}{M_{c}(f)}\leq\dfrac{2^{n}}{v_{n}}, \quad \dfrac{2^{n}}{(v_{n}n^{n/2})}\leq\dfrac{\mathcal{M}(f)}{\mathcal{M}_{c}(f)}\leq\dfrac{2^{n}}{v_{n}}\qquad\text{a.e.},$$
>   where $v_{n}$ denotes the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

*Proof.* In what follows, $r>0$. Replacing $f$ by a translate, it suffices to establish the inequality at $x=0$. Observe that the cube $[-r,r]^{n}$ is almost everywhere contained in the open ball $B(0,n^{1/2}r)$. Whence,

$$\dfrac{1}{v_{n}n^{n/2}r^{n}}\int_{[-r,r]^{n}}\left|f\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{v_{n}n^{n/2}r^{n}}\int_{B(0,n^{1/2}r)}\left|f\right|=\dfrac{1}{\left|B(0,n^{1/2}r)\right|}\int_{B(0,n^{1/2}r)}\left|f\right|\leq Mf(0)$$

Multiplying by $1=2^{n}/2^{n}$ and taking the supremum over $r>0$ of the LHS, we obtain that

$$\dfrac{2^{n}}{v_{n}n^{n/2}}M_{c}f(0)\leq Mf(0)$$

Similarly, observe that the open ball $B(0,r)$ is contained in the cube $[-r,r]^{n}$. Whence,

$$\dfrac{1}{(2r)^{n}}\int_{B(0,r)}\left|f\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{(2r)^{n}}\int_{[-r,r]^{n}}\left|f\right|\leq M_{c}f(0)$$
Multiplying by $1=v_{n}/v_{n}$ and taking the supremum over $r>0$ of the LHS, we obtain that

$$\dfrac{v_{n}}{2^{n}}Mf(0)\leq M_{c}f(0)$$
A completely analogous argument establishes the inequality for the uncentered maximal functions. $\Box$

It's worth mentioning that these inequalities show that $\mathcal{M}_{c},\mathcal{M}$ are weak-type (1,1) operators and therefore are bounded operators $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\rightarrow L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for $1<p\leq\infty$.